# FTP Login Cracker

Tags: java, ftp

I am currently developing a program that will eventually do "dictionary attacks", this is a university project, so it not for illegal purposes.

Okay So far I have manage to achieve this:

```
public class Cracker {

public static void main(String [] args) throws IOException {

    BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("/bin/a.txt"));
    StringBuffer stringBuffer = new StringBuffer();
    String line = null;

    while((line =bufferedReader.readLine())!=null) {
        stringBuffer.append(line).append("\n");
    }

    System.out.println(stringBuffer);
  }
}
```

So what this does it reads from a *.txt file and print out every line of it. I am not too familiar with connection in Java, so I was wondering how I can implement this same concept and use it to try each line for the password of the FTP server. The lectures have provided the user so there is no need to do it for the user.

Thanks in advance for everyone who helps.

Comment: There are several Java based FTP libraries you could use.  Just Google "Java FTP client".  If you can't use a client lib, then you are going to have to read and understand how FTP works and implement it.  Or, I guess you could shell out and call the FTP command line program.  Raw "connections" in Java are typically done with a `Socket`, which gives access to raw Input/Output streams.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As CodeChimp suggested you could use existing FTP clients for Java. If this is not an option for you, you can implement the authorization process yourself.

The FTP protocol is pretty well described on [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File_Transfer_Protocol).

The authorization process can be implemented as follows:

1. Open a connection on port `21` to the FTP server. The server should respond with status code `2xx` (usually `220`)
2. Send the command `USER <username>`. The server should respond with the status code `3xx`
3. Send the command `PASS <password>`. The server will respond with status code `230` (successful login) or status code `430`.

You can test the authorization process in advance using a telnet client.

Opening a connection programmatically in Java you usually have to use a `Socket`. [Here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/networking/sockets/readingWriting.html) you will find a tutorial for reading and writing data from/to `Socket`s.

Comment: Thank you very much, I really needed a base where to get started on, I going some material just started reading it. Thank you for the tips